# How do I gracefully include Python 3.3 from None exception syntax in a Python 3.2 program?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.2, python-3.3, forward-compatibility

I'm trying to re-raise an exception to give the user better information about the actual error. Python 3.3 includes [PEP 409](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0409/). It adds the `raise NewException from None` syntax to suppress the context of the original exception.

However, I am targeting Python 3.2. The Python script will parse, but at runtime if it encounters the `from None` syntax it will produce  `TypeError: exception causes must derive from BaseException`. For example:

```
try:
    regex_c = re.compile('^{}$'.format(regex)) 
except re.error as e:
    e_msg = 'Regular expression error in "{}"'.format(regex)
    e_reraise = Exception(e_msg)
    # Makes use of the new Python 3.3 exception syntax [from None]
    # to suppress the context of the original exception
    # Causes an additional TypeError exception in Python 3.2
    raise e_reraise from None
```

Encapsulating `raise e_reraise from None` in a `try` just produces an even larger exception stacktrace. A version check doesn't work either, since my `python3.3` on Xubuntu 12.10 pulls modules from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/*` which was is setup for python3.2 modules. (You get a convenient `Error in sys.excepthook:` which creates a **massive** traceback.)

Is there a way to use the PEP 409 feature when running in Python 3.3, while silently ignoring it in Python 3.2?

Comment: What's wrong with a version check?

Comment: @wRAR Version checking doesn't seem to work on systems like mine, which have the python3.3 interpreter but use a common python3 stdlib that is set up for a different version (python3.2 in my case).

Comment: @SumantManne: and what do you think `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` gives you in that case then?

Comment: Yes, it's expected that some code won't work on fundamentally broken systems, but it's not a problem of that code (OTOH I'm not sure how the `sys` module is related to the stdlib as it's builtin).

Comment: @wRAR The `sys` module is statically linked to the interpreter, which means you can **always** tell which version of python is being executed, hence the OP comment doesn't make much sense. By the way: the dirty solution could be to replace `sys.excepthook` with something that removes the extra tracebacks you don't want in the case of a `raise ... from None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PEP you linked provides the solution:

> - `raise NewException() from None`
>
> Follows existing syntax of explicitly declaring the originating
>   exception
>
> - `exc = NewException(); exc.__context__ = None; raise exc`
>
> Very verbose way of the previous method

So, you simply have to avoid the new syntax and use the verbose equivalent.

If you don't want to see the assignments you can put the code into a function:

```
def suppress_context(exc):
    exc.__context__ = None
    return exc
```

And then do:

```
raise suppress_context(TheErrorClass())
```

**Edit:** as pointed out by Martijn [PEP 415](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0415/) changed this behaviour:

> To summarize, `raise exc from cause` will be equivalent to:
>
> ```
> exc.__cause__ = cause
> raise exc
> ```

Thus, instead of setting `__context__` to `None` you should set `__cause__` to `None`.

If you really want to use the new syntax, then the only way to do this is to replace `sys.excepthook` with something that parses the traceback output and removes the the parts that you don't want. But in this case you also *must* do this:

```
try:
    raise error from None
except TypeError:
    raise error
```

Then the `excepthook` should search the traceback and if it should remove the parts related to the `raise error from None` line. Not a simple task and you end up with more code than the other solution.

Comment: Not `__context__`, but **`__cause__`** should be set to `None`. I tried `__context__` as well and nothing is changed (nor does setting `__suppress_context__` work). PEP 409 was amended by PEP 415.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Correct, I'm fixing this now.

Comment: Humble suggestion: Why don't we put the *currently correct* code at the top of the post so that the modern answer is read first before the historically correct answer?

Answer (score 5):

You can set `exc.__cause__ = None` to suppress the context printing in Python 3.3:

```
except re.error as e:
    e_msg = 'Regular expression error in "{}"'.format(regex)
    e_reraise = Exception(e_msg)
    e_reraise.__cause__ = None  # 'raise e_reraise from None'
    raise e_reraise
```

In Python 3.3, when you use `raise exc from cause` what really happens is:

```
exc.__cause__ = cause
raise exc
```

and setting `exc.__cause__` in turn implicitly sets `exc.__suppress_context__ = True`. See [PEP 415](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0415/), which details how `raise exc from None` is handled.

When you set `exc.__cause__ = None` in Python 3.2, nothing changes:

```
$ python3.2
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 13 2012, 13:31:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.12)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> try:
...     raise ValueError()
... except:
...     exc = TypeError()
...     exc.__cause__ = None
...     raise exc
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError
```

But in Python 3.3, the context is suppressed instead:

```
$ python3.3
Python 3.3.0 (default, Sep 29 2012, 08:16:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> try:
...     raise ValueError()
... except:
...     exc = TypeError()
...     exc.__cause__ = None
...     raise exc
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError
```

just as if you had used `raise exc from None`:

```
>>> try:
...     raise ValueError()
... except:
...     raise TypeError() from None
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError
```